# Windows Media Center, play ASX file using internal player

Tags: windows-media-center

Is there a way, I can play a ASX file using internal media player?

Details: I am using "Media Center Studio" to add ASX link ("Application"), but it opens up actual Windows Media player by coming out of MCE and playing again inside MCE. I was wondering is there way I can use internal player to play an ASX file.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb189661.aspx) mentions that there's only "limited" support for ASX playlists.

Your description mentions that in the end, MCE is used for playing the content. Isn't that your desired end result?

You might also try associating permanently the ASX extension with Media Center instead of WMP as it must currently be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...that was my desired end result. But it looked awkward when it gets out of WMC and comes back.

I guess the issue was having an http:// in the front, WMC was trying to open it in IE and then switching it back. I fixed this by having another ASX file locally and made that one point to http:// seems to be fixed and quite a nice experience. Thanks.